# MessageResponse returns null pointer in Watson Conversation

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, chatbot, watson-conversation

`MessageResponse` gives a `NullPointerException`.

```
ConversationService service = new ConversationService(ConversationService.VERSION_DATE_2016_09_20);
// Credentials of Workspace of Conversation
service.setApiKey("API_KEY");
service.setUsernameAndPassword("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder()
  .inputText(request.getQuery())
  .build();

// Workspace ID of Conversation current workspace
String workspaceId = "WORKSPACEID";
service.setSkipAuthentication(true);
MessageResponse response = service.message(workspaceId, newMessage)
  .execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Conversation service doesn't use `api_key` but `username` and `password`

There are two erros in your code snippet:
 1. `setApiKey()` is not required when using Conversation.
 1. `service.setSkipAuthentication(true);` will instruct the SDK to ignore the service credentials, therefore, they are not being sent to the server on each request.

You just need to remove the line `service.setSkipAuthentication(true);`.

```
ConversationService service = new ConversationService(ConversationService.VERSION_DATE_2016_09_20);
// Credentials of Workspace of Conversation
// BTW: This are not your Bluemix credentials!
service.setUsernameAndPassword("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder()
  .inputText("Hi! this is my first message to Watson")
  .build();

MessageResponse response = service.message("WORKSPACEID", newMessage)
  .execute();
System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: Your answer explains exactly what the user needs to know. Upvote. @Parker, consider marking this answer like correct.

Comment: I upvoted yours as it links to important material we want users to see

Answer (score 3):

According to the IBM Developer (@German): "The Watson services currently use Basic Auth so instead of an api_key you will use username and password. In order to get the credentials, you need to bind the service you want to use (e.g. Question and Answer) to a Bluemix application."

**Check the following examples.**

Try to use the following code from [Java SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/develop/conversation):

```
ConversationService service = new ConversationService(ConversationService.VERSION_DATE_2017_05_26);
service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>"); //Please make sure if this username and password is the Service Credentials from the Service that you have created to use Conversation

InputData input = new InputData.Builder("Hi").build();
MessageOptions options = new MessageOptions.Builder(workspaceId).input(input).build();

// sync
MessageResponse response = service.message(options).execute();
System.out.println(response);
```

Other example:

```
MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText(input).context(context).build();

MessageResponse response = service.message(WORKSPACE_ID,newMessage).execute();

context = response.getContext();    
System.out.println(response);
```

- You can see the *Official* [example](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/develop/examples/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/conversation/v1/ConversationExample.java) using Watson Conversation.
- See the Started Guide for using Watson Services (Step 5) [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/index.html#about).

Comment: Please mark the answer if this helps you and follows the 'How to answer' on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). But consider to verify the answer by @German Attanasio, he explains to you why your code does not work and he's work at IBM focused on Watson Developer Cloud (The SDK's that we uses to code with Watson)